# Flask & Bootstrap remote modal POST

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I have a view in Flask that renders remote content of the Bootstrap modal. The content of the modal is a form.

```
@app.route("/alerts/edit<int:alertID>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

The modal content is being rendered on button press from the parent view:

```
@app.route("/alerts", methods=["GET"])
```

My modal has a submit button. When I press the button a POST request is being generated correctly. Unfortunately the POST request is being handled by the parent view ("/alerts") instead of the modal view ("/alerts/edit") giving me "The method POST is not allowed for the requested URL." error.

Is there any way to force remote modal view to process the POST request instead of the parent view?

EDIT:
I'm not using AJAX. A snippet from my modal html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">E-mail</span>
                <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value="{{request.form.emailAddress}}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{alert.email}}" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your form have an `action` attribute pointing at `/alerts/edit/123` (or, if you are using AJAX are you making sure to prevent the form's default behavior)?

Comment: Obviously, my form missed the action attribute. After adding this as you suggested everything works as expected. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding action attribute as suggested by Sean Vieira solved the problem.